# Creating a multidimensional, associative array with unknown amounts of loops out of json

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So, I am receiving json input. I don't know how many inputs I will receive. I know how to turn this into an array, however I need to mix up how the array is structured. Array is currently multidimensional and associative already however is using the wrong associations. For me, it's using 'label' and 'value but I need these two to be in one associative array which use 'x' and 'y' so I can use them in a chart.

Example json

```
{
    "metingen": [
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:13:38",
            "value": 25.21
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:51:04",
            "value": 27.69
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:52:04",
            "value": 27.69
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:53:06",
            "value": 27.61
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:54:08",
            "value": 27.56
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:55:08",
            "value": 27.55
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:56:09",
            "value": 27.55
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 13:57:09",
            "value": 27.53
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:05:12",
            "value": 28.51
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:06:12",
            "value": 28.53
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:07:13",
            "value": 28.51
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:08:13",
            "value": 28.51
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:09:14",
            "value": 28.53
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:10:14",
            "value": 28.52
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:11:15",
            "value": 28.52
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:12:15",
            "value": 28.54
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:13:16",
            "value": 28.53
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:14:16",
            "value": 28.48
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:15:17",
            "value": 28.39
        },
        {
            "label": "06-06-2019 14:16:17",
            "value": 28.37
        }
    ],
    "title": "Temperature for ICT Boven"
}
```

The PHP I'm using

```php
$dataPoints = array();
foreach($charts as $key=> $chart)
{
    $j=0;
    $x=$chart[0]['label'];
    $y=$chart[0]['value'];
    $i=array($x,$y);
    $dataPoints[0]=$i;
}
```

```php
dataPoints array
(
   array("x"=>"06-06-2019 13:13:38","y"=>25.21)//And then a lot of these arrays
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map with array_combine as follows,

```
$temp['metingen'] = array_map(function ($item) {
    return array_combine(['x', 'y'], $item); // x and y are keys and label and value are values
}, $temp['metingen']);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/k211D)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` with `json_decode`

```
$jToArr = json_decode($json, true);
$res = [];
foreach($jToArr['metingen'] as $key => $value){
  $res[] = ['x' => $value['label'], 'y' => $value['value']];
}
print_r($res);
```

[Working DEMO](https://3v4l.org/7hcoJ)